# optimize my query mysql - PHP

Tags: mysql

I have this query that takes more than 10 seconds, 
The most bulky table is requetes, the clause where depends on filter:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  requetes.id AS thread_id,
  requetes.id AS thread_id2,  
  CONCAT_WS("/", SUBSTR(requetes.id, 5, 2), SUBSTR(requetes.id, 3, 2), SUBSTR(requetes.id, 1, 2)) AS thread_create_date, 
  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i") AS create_date, 
  IF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requetes.date_objectif_requete) = 0, NULL, DATE_FORMAT(requetes.date_objectif_requete, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S")) AS thread_target_date,
  IF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requetes.date_objectif_requete) = 0, NULL, DATE_FORMAT(requetes.date_objectif_requete, "%Y%m%d")) AS int_thread_target_date,

  requetes.prenom AS customer_first_name,
  requetes.nom AS customer_last_name,
  requetes.subject AS subject_action,
  requetes.ident_e AS code_customer,
  CONCAT_WS(" ", UPPER(requetes.nom), requetes.prenom, requetes.pseudo) AS complete_customer_name,
  requetes.type_rs AS type_rs,
  themes_sous.id AS thread_type_id,
  requetes.cp AS zip_code,
  requetes.libelle_pc_origine AS libelle_pc_origine,
  themes_sous.libelle AS thread_type_label,
  themes_sous.action_page AS thread_type_target_url,
  agents.prenom AS user_first_name,
  agents.nom AS user_last_name,
  req_agent.id_agent AS code_user,
  CONCAT_WS(" ", UPPER(agents.nom), agents.prenom) AS complete_user_name,
  (1 - statut_inverse) AS done,
  archive AS archived,
  num_messages,
  themes.libelle AS libelle_categ

  FROM requetes
  LEFT OUTER JOIN themes_sous
  ON requetes.id_ss_theme = themes_sous.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN req_agent
  ON requetes.id = req_agent.id_requete
  LEFT OUTER JOIN agents
  ON req_agent.id_agent = agents.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN themes
  ON themes.id = themes_sous.id_theme  
  WHERE requetes.client_identifier=4
  AND themes_sous.client_identifier=4
  AND requetes.statut_inverse = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(requetes.date_objectif_requete, "%Y%m%d") <> 20171215 AND NOT (DATE_FORMAT(requetes.date_objectif_requete, "%Y%m%d") > 20171215) AND ( req_agent.id_agent_origine = "5087050" )  AND requetes.date_objectif_requete IS NOT NULL AND requetes.date_objectif_requete <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
  ORDER BY requetes.id LIMIT 0, 25;
```

The explain of this query is :
[explain of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIhqW.png)

[config of the most bulky table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9XA.png)

thanks for your help

Comment: why do you explain your query in a linked resource?

Comment: More the joins more the time it takes, add one more join and it may double the execution time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you need more explication ?